# Vuetify 2.x v-data-table Keyboard Commands/Navigation

Tags: vue.js, accessibility, vuetify.js

It appears that in Vuetify 2.x it is not possible to navigate v-data-tables out of the box, when this was a previously implemented feature in versions 1.5.x. Is there any simple work around for this or any reasoning as to why these keyboard commands were removed?

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear why the feature was removed,

but If you checking the [vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) repository, It seems that this was a regression BUG and there are multiple request for this feature to be added back.

Therefore, I suppose it will be fixed in the near future. (Since the last issue mention has been made 15 days ago).

Here are some relevant issues on their repository:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9289

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9060

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9164

Comment: While it's not the answer I was hoping to get, it's probably in the works from the Vuetify team. Thanks.